# Java regex and pattern matching: finding "blanks" in pattern which do not include them?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

So, I need to write a compiler scanner for a homework, and thought it'd be "elegant" to use regex. Fact is, I seldomly used them before, and it was a long time ago. So I forgot most of the stuff about them and needed to have a look around. I used them successfully for the identifiers (or at least I think so, I still need to do some further tests but for now they all look ok), but I have a problem with the numbers-recognition.

The function `nextCh()` reads the next character on the input (lookahead char). What I'd like to do here is to check if this char matches the regex `[0-9]*`. I append every matching char in the `str` field of my current token, then I read the int value of this field. It recognizes a single number input such as "123", but the problem I have is that for the input "123 456", the final str will be "123 456" while I should get 2 separate tokens with fields "123" and "456". Why is the " " being matched?

```
private void readNumber(Token t) {
    t.str = "" + ch; // force conversion char --> String
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*");
    nextCh(); // get next char and check if it is a digit
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher("" + ch);
    while (match.find() && ch != EOF) {
        t.str += ch;
        nextCh();
        match = pattern.matcher("" + ch);
    }
    t.kind = Kind.number;
    try {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(t.str);            
        t.val = value;          
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        error(t, Message.BIG_NUM, t.str);           
    }
```

Thank you!

PS: I did solve my problem using the code below. Nevertheless, I'd like to understand where the flaw is in my regex expression.

```
    t.str = "" + ch;
    nextCh(); // get next char and check if it is a number
    while (ch>='0' && ch<='9') {
        t.str += ch;
        nextCh();
    }
    t.kind = Kind.number;
    try {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(t.str);            
        t.val = value;          
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        error(t, Message.BIG_NUM, t.str);           
    }
```

**EDIT:** turns out my regex also doesn't work for the identifiers recognition (again, includes blanks), so I had to switch to a system similar to my "solution" (while with a lot of conditions). Guess I'll need to study the regex again :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `matches` method rather than the `find` method.  From the documentation:

> The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern
>
> The find method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.

So in other words, by using `find`, if the string *contains* a digit anywhere at all, you'll get a match, but if you use `matches` the entire string must match the pattern.

For example, try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*");
Matcher m123abc = p.matcher("123 abc");
System.out.println(m123abc.matches());  // prints false
System.out.println(m123abc.find());     // prints true
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure whether this is relevant in your case, but this:

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9]*");
```

matches **zero or more** numbers anywhere in the string, because of the asterisk. I think the space gets matched because it is a match for 'zero numbers'. If you wanted to make sure the char was a number, you would have to match **one or more**, using the plus sign:

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
```

or, since you are only comparing a single char at a time, just match **one** number:

```
Pattern.compile("^[0-9]$");
```

Comment: I tried the 3. With your two extra possibilities unfortunately I couldn't even detect the "123" number... I might need to recheck the code. Another question: could you tell me what the ^ symbol does? I couldn't really follow the example I found the other day...

Comment: The `^` means the string will be matched from the start. The `$` means matched from the end. Thus if you bookend the regex with `^` and `$`, it means the string must exactly match. Without them, something like `' rdpa5'` would match just the same as `'5'` would, because there is a number present *somewhere* in the string. Of course, if you are only comparing a single char each time, I don't think the bookends make much of a difference.

Comment: By the way, if it is not matching at all anymore, it might be because you are including the forward-slashes. You don't need them if you construct RegExp using the constructor, like you are doing. I'll update the answer....

Comment: This isn't quite right.  The pattern the OP is using is fine, it's the `Matcher` method that's wrong.  See my answer.

Comment: Oh. Cool! Great thing about SO, even when you're not asking the question you can learn something :-D

Answer (score 0):

Use a simpler regex like

```
/\d+/
```

Where

- `\d` means a digit
- `+` means one or more

In code:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
```

Comment: probably it's too late (3:30 am) for me to be doing java. I tried to put your regex but eclipse tells me that \d is an invalid escapte sequence...

Comment: thanks for edit. unluckily it won't find any number (I'll debug tomorrow to see what it's doing exactly)... this is weird